python selenium webdriver.Chromeが遅い
ウェブで調べても分からなかったので質問させてください。
事象
Pythonでseleniumを使ってウェブページを開こうとすると
webdriver.Chrome()の実行に5分程度かかり かつ Basic認証が正常に動作しない。
コード実行時にVSCode左下の「コールスタック」欄に以下が実行中と表示されます。
なお別環境では同じコードの実行はスムーズに完了します。
MainThread
Thread-6(_readerthread)
Thread-7(_readerthread)

環境
Windows 11 Pro 64bit
VSCode 1.90.2
Python 3.12.3（python-3.12.3-amd64.exe）
Selenium 4.22.0
Chrome: 126.0.6478.127（Official Build） （64 ビット）
コード
basic_url = f'https://{basic_username}:{basic_password}@{url}'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(basic_url)

以下のURLが同じ事象のような気がするのですが解決法がわかりませんでした。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76957026/chromedriver-starts-chrome-as-x86-64-translated-on-m1-very-slow-performance
